# Using PHP to compile XML from an API, how to use foreach to create multiple child nodes

Tags: php, xml, foreach

I'm working with a poorly documented API and for it to be compatible with the third party program I'm using, it is necessary to convert it into a tailored XML feed.

Some of the results contain multiple values e.g. the **images** node contains an **image** node but there could be ten images which all need to reside in their own node.

I'm wanting to use a `foreach` statement to populate each child node with the required URL but what I've done doesn't work as I don't know the syntax required.

```
<?php

/* Set Content Type to XML and Charset to UTF-8 */
header( "content-type: application/xml; charset=utf-8" );

/* Create XML Document */
$xml = new DOMDocument( "1.0", "utf-8" );

/* Create Nodes */
$my_images = $xml->createElement( "images" );
$my_image = $xml->createElement( "image", foreach($property['gallery']['images'] as $image) { $image['url']['large'] } );
```

My expected output is:

```
<images>
    <image>example.com/image1.png</image>
    <image>example.com/image2.png</image>
    <image>example.com/image3.png</image>
</images>
```

Everything appears to be working fine until I get to nodes where the result needs to be exploded and a foreach statement used.

**EDIT**

Wondering if the the foreach loop can be used to appendChild? `$my_images->appendChild( $my_image );`

Comment: For simplicity, I would be very tempted to forget about `DOMDocument` (what benefit does it give you?).  I would just use my favourite HTML templating engine (even just PHP itself).  Instead of HTML tags, you'll be outputting XML tags.  I wouldn't use `DOMDocument` to create XHTML, so I wouldn't for plain XML.

Answer (score 0):

a short answer :

```
<?php
/* Set Content Type to XML and Charset to UTF-8 */
header( "content-type: application/xml; charset=utf-8" );

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<images/>');

foreach($property['gallery']['images'] as $image) { 
  $xml->addChild('image',$image['url']['large']);
}

print $xml->asXML();
```

results in :

```
<images>
    <image>example.com/image1.png</image>
    <image>example.com/image2.png</image>
    <image>example.com/image3.png</image>
</images>
```

Comment: Would this work where there are multiple nodes?

e.g.

`<node1>lorem ipsum</node1>
<node2>lorem ipsum</node2>
<node3>lorem ipsum</node3>
<images>
    <image>example.com/image1.png</image>
    <image>example.com/image2.png</image>
    <image>example.com/image3.png</image>
</images>
<node5>lorem ipsum</node6>`

Comment: Also, the right brace is throwing a syntax error that it's not expected. missing a semi-colon after the right track on line 8.